# Strange behavior of toolbox compilation when referencing an inner static java class

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-2.10, toolbox

Supposed I have the following java class:

```
package com.test;
public class Outer {
    public static class Inner { public static final String VAL = "Inner"; }
}
```

I can reference the `VAL` constant from scala code just as you would expect but when I try compiling code that references this field using the scala toolbox compiler, it fails. (stacktrace follows the example below).

This code demonstrated what I mean:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
object Issue extends App {
  val mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val toolbox = ToolBox(mirror).mkToolBox()
  println                  (com.test.Outer.Inner.VAL) // prints 'Inner'
  val tree = toolbox.parse("com.test.Outer.Inner.VAL")
  val compiled = toolbox.compile(tree)() // fails to compile
}
```

This is the the exception trace I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed: 

value Inner is not a member of object com.test.Outer
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.throwIfErrors(ToolBoxFactory.scala:319)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:252)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:416)
    at Issue$delayedInit$body.apply(Issue.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at Issue$.main(Issue.scala:3)
    at Issue.main(Issue.scala)
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there anything I can change (i.e compiler options) to make this work?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I get when I compile with "-verbose -Yissue-debug":

```
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala package package and package scala, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package java
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package lang
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package runtime
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package annotation
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala package package and package runtime, owner = package runtime
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package collection
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala package package and package collection, owner = package collection
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.lang.Object
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Unit and object Unit, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.lang.Throwable
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Long and object Long, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.lang.InterruptedException
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Int and object Int, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Boolean and object Boolean, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.lang.String
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package io
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java interface java.io.Serializable
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java interface java.lang.CharSequence
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Char and object Char, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.io.ObjectStreamField
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package util
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Float and object Float, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Double and object Double, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Byte and object Byte, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.lang.StringBuffer
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.util.Locale
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package nio
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package charset
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.nio.charset.Charset
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class java.lang.StringBuilder
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java interface java.lang.Comparable
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package beans
parsing com.test.Outer.Inner.VAL
importing com.test.Outer.Inner.VAL
compiling com.test.Outer.Inner.VAL
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Predef and object Predef, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class ClassfileAnnotation and object ClassfileAnnotation, owner = package annotation
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Annotation and object Annotation, owner = package annotation
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class StaticAnnotation and object StaticAnnotation, owner = package annotation
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package reflect
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala package package and package reflect, owner = package reflect
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala package package and package api, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Universe and object Universe, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Symbols and object Symbols, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Types and object Types, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class FlagSets and object FlagSets, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Scopes and object Scopes, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Names and object Names, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Trees and object Trees, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Constants and object Constants, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Annotations and object Annotations, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Positions and object Positions, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Exprs and object Exprs, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class TypeTags and object TypeTags, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class TagInterop and object TagInterop, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class StandardDefinitions and object StandardDefinitions, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class StandardNames and object StandardNames, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class BuildUtils and object BuildUtils, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Mirrors and object Mirrors, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Printers and object Printers, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Importers and object Importers, owner = package api
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package runtime
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala package package and package runtime, owner = package runtime
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class StringContext and object StringContext, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Product and object Product, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Equals and object Equals, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Serializable and object Serializable, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package immutable
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala package package and package immutable, owner = package immutable
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Array and object Array, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java interface java.lang.Cloneable
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class AnyVal and object AnyVal, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class NotNull and object NotNull, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class LowPriorityImplicits and object LowPriorityImplicits, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package com
[reflect-compiler] unpickling Scala class Dynamic and object Dynamic, owner = package scala
[reflect-compiler] made Scala package test
[reflect-compiler] translating reflection info for Java class com.test.Outer
[reflect-compiler] *** missing: Inner/true/object Outer/false/class scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedOps$$anon$1
java.lang.Exception
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.issue(Contexts.scala:399)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.ContextErrors$ErrorUtils$.issueTypeError(ContextErrors.scala:84)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.ContextErrors$ErrorUtils$.issueNormalTypeError(ContextErrors.scala:69)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.ContextErrors$TyperContextErrors$TyperErrorGen$.NotAMemberError(ContextErrors.scala:331)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.handleMissing$1(Typers.scala:4846)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedSelect$1(Typers.scala:4851)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4938)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5551)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5630)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5710)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5716)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4918)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5551)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5630)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5825)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:2250)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5557)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5630)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:2921)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3025)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3025)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:170)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:186)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3025)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1914)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedModuleDef(Typers.scala:1794)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5572)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5630)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:2921)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3025)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$62.apply(Typers.scala:3025)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:170)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:186)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3025)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5288)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5575)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5630)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5687)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.apply(Analyzer.scala:99)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:463)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.run(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1582)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1556)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:251)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:416)
    at Issue$delayedInit$body.apply(Issue.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at Issue$.main(Issue.scala:3)
    at Issue.main(Issue.scala)
Exception in thread "main" scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed: 

[namer in 31ms]
[packageobjects in 0ms]
value Inner is not a member of object com.test.Outer
[typer in 211ms]
[total in 247ms]
[reset] recursing in package <root>
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.throwIfErrors(ToolBoxFactory.scala:319)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:252)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:416)
    at Issue$delayedInit$body.apply(Issue.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at Issue$.main(Issue.scala:3)
    at Issue.main(Issue.scala)
```

**EDIT 2**

I think this is a bug in the reflection API but i'm not sure.
I've debugged the typing phase and have come up with the following:

After `com.test.Outer` has been assigned with an appropriate symbol, we reach the the typing phase of `com.test.Outer.Inner`.

There it looks up a symbol for `Inner` using `scala.reflect.internal.Scopes.Scope#lookupEntry(Name)`.

Inspecting the looked upon scope reveals that it does contain a `ScopeEntry` for a `ClassSymbol` of `Inner` but the equality testing between the scope symbol name and methods `name` parameter is done using `Object#equals` (i.e. `equals` has not been overriden), 
and the two name instances are not the same.

One last note regarding the symbol's name and the passed name parameter is that I see they have the same `index` field. I'm not sure what this means, but I got the impression this means they refer to the same name in the name table, so they are equal (?)
(There is one difference between the two though, one is `TermName` and the symbol's name is a `TypeName`).

Anyway, I'll probably open a bug Scala's bug tracker, just wanted to conclude things here.

Comment: Try `toolbox.parse("com.test.Outer#Inner.VAL")`?

Comment: Yes, please, submit a bug, and I will take a look. Thanks for the detailed analysis!

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Thanks, just opened SI-7378

Comment: Well the static Inner class is in fact a static member of the Outer class, not a member of the instance of Outer. Consult the documentation, perhaps there is another way to deal with static objects and fields?

Answer (score -1):

Correct - it looks like the Scala / JVM reflection API is not able to determine that VAR is a static member of the nested Inner class.